# Mongoose: findOne method does not complete/has odd behaviour when called inside Array.map

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I have an endpoint that receives an array of strings and I would like to populate another array with the results of a Mongoose search with the parameters of the request body. My code inside `app.post("/whee", function (req, res)`goes like so.

```
var SU = db.model("SignUp", supModel)
var dab = req.body.map(function(x) {
    return SU.findOne({"email": x}, function(err, data){
           if(err) throw err;
           return data;
           });
    });
console.log(dab);
```

If I send a request, what I get when I print `dab` to the console is this:

```
[ { _mongooseOptions: {},
mongooseCollection: 
 { collection: [Object],
   opts: [Object],
   name: 'signups',
   conn: [Object],
   queue: [],
   buffer: false },
model: 
 { [Function: model]
   base: [Object],
   modelName: 'SignUp',
   model: [Function: model],
   db: [Object],
   discriminators: undefined,
   schema: [Object],
   options: undefined,
   collection: [Object] },
op: 'findOne',
options: {},
_conditions: { email: 'hello@sample.com' },
_fields: undefined,
_update: undefined,
_path: undefined,
_distinct: undefined,
_collection: { collection: [Object] },
_castError: null } ]
```

Obviously, `hello@sample.com` was an element of the array I sent in the request. For simplicity's sake, you can assume the element is already a value inside a document in my mongo datastore. What's going on? Why am I receiving this garble instead of my document? Calling the `forEach` method and pushing the results into `dab` only renders an empty array, which makes sense considering it's a synchronous method.

Any ideas as to how to fix this?

Comment: `findOne` is asynchronous - you can't return data from the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Try using async.

https://www.npmjs.org/package/async

```
var SU = db.model("SignUp", supModel);
var dab = [];

async.each(req.body, function(email, callback) {
  SU.findOne({"email": email}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
    } else {
      dab.push(data);
      callback();
    }
  });    
}, function(err) {
  console.log(dab);
});
```